How to tell if a macro parameter is a command sequence
my first ever question.
I've primarily been using LateX, and not delving into the innards of TeX, but maybe that time has come.
Suppose I have a macro someMacro, which expects one argument.
If the argument is just plain text (characters to be typeset), I want the macro to emit that text.
If, however, the argument is a command-sequence, I want the macro to invoke the command-sequence, and attach an extra parameter to the end.
Thus the effect of:
someMacro(abcd) is to typeset "abcd"
But the effect of:
someMacro{\someCommand{p1}{p2}...{pn}}
is to invoke \someCommand{p1}{p2}...{pn}{withExtraParam}.
I think I could easily implement this if there was a simple way of asking "is #1 just text" or "is #1 expandable".
If this is trivially doable, I apologise, but I cannot for the life of me work out what question to ask on the web to find the answer.
Ok, my apologies for the overly-brief question --- I was trying to be brief.
Thank you for the information so far.
Let me elaborate...
The application is perhaps unusual --- I am using LaTeX to typeset Latin.  In Latin, a noun has 6 different case-endings depending on its use in the sentence   I have created a dictionary of words and some LaTeX magic that allows me to write (say) \amicusFriend{g} (which specifies the noun amicus to be put in the genitive case), and the result is the same as me typing amic={\i}.  The "magic" I have created also can supply a literal (word-for-word) English translation --- in this case it would show "of-friend".  This works fine for very many nouns and adjectives and verbs, but in some cases the English translation needs to be inflected depending on the case that is selected.  This happens, for example, with personal pronouns. The first person pronoun in Latin is ego/me/mei/mihi/me.  In English it is I/me/mine/toOrfor-me/byOrWithOrFrom-me.
So my application arises when I create a dictionary entry.  To make an entry for amicus, I type:
\defNoun{amicusFriend}{M}{\declTwoMF{amicus}{amic}}{friend}.
This specifies that the noun "amicuSfriend" is masculine, of the secondDeclension (declTwoMF), with two critical pieces of information that define the pattern are "amicus" and amic", and finally that the English meaning is "friend".
When I define a person pronoun, there's a similar definition:
\defPronoun{egoI}(some irrelevantDetail here){englishMeaning}.
In this case "englishMeaning" needs to be a macro that will generate the correct inflected English form, based on the case I select (the {g} in the earlier example)
Most of the time, the English meaning is fixed --- the need for an inflectable form arises in only a very small number of cases)
So to get this to work I'd like to be able to write:
\defPronoun{egoI}(irrelevantDetail here){\inflectMacro}.
Where I have replaced the fixed English meaning with a macto "inflectMacro".
When the pronoun is used, inflectMacro will be expanded in a context where it is followed by the the correct case-code:
\inflectMacro{g}.
It would be REALLY nice if, during a definition, I could write:
\def....{\inflectMacro{p1}{p2}...{pn}}
and have this expand later as:
\inflectMacro{p1}{p2}...{pn}{g}
(where the {g} is the required case-code}
Clearly,what I seek does not have to work for ANY macro, just with macros that have 1 parameter, and "make sense" in my application.
My apologies for the long explanation.

Welcome! can you turn your snippet into something somewhat compilable? and maybe tell us what you're actually using this for? something may be not-expandable without being simple text. is \someCommand expandable? you seem to think it is, but I suspect you probably haven't thought of it not being expandable ;). a lot depends on the details here, especially the way the macro will be used. do you need it to handle arbitrary user input? or do you only need to deal with a couple of possibilities for things generated by other code?

As an aside, from your description you don't want to know whether the parameter is a macro, but whether the first token of your parameter is a macro.

you could do this (with some limitations) but are you sure you want to do this, it will give a behaviour rather unlike any other latex command if a user has \newcommand\me{David}  in their document then generally they can use \me instead of David but in the argument of your command these would be very different.

You didn't provide any test code, so this answer doesn't show any usages, but the following should implement what you need in expl3:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\someMacro{m}
  { \davidK_some_macro:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \davidK_some_macro:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF {#1}
      { \__davidK_some_macro:en { \tl_head:n {#1} } {#1} }
      {#1}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__davidK_some_macro:nn #1#2
  {
    \token_if_macro:NTF #1
      { #2 { withExtraParam } }
      {#2}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__davidK_some_macro:nn { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

Put it in your preamble and use \someMacro. You might want to change withExtraParam to whatever you need.

If you want to test, if a first token of a used parameter is a control sequence not equal to a character, then you can use \if\noexpand#1\relax at TeX primitive level. First of all, you have to get the first token to the #1 parameter which cannot be done directly, if the parameter is written in {...} and it can include more tokens. So, the code below repeats the composed parameter finalized by \end and the next macro \someMacroA gets the first token to #1 and the rest to #2.
\def\someMacro#1{\someMacroA#1\end}
\def\someMacroA#1#2\end{%
   \if\noexpand#1\relax
      #1#2{additional parameters}% #1 is a macro or a control sequence not equal to a letter
   \else #1#2% #1#2 is normal text
   \fi
}

%% Test:

\def\someCommand #1#2#3#4{1="#1", 2="#2", 3="#3, 4="#4"}  

\someMacro{text} % prints text

\someMacro{\someCommand{p1}{p2}{p3}} % prints 1="p1", 2="p2", 3="p3, 4="additional parameters""

\bye

